# Amplitude and Phase of a Periodic Signal (Fourier Series)

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Please consider the following  periodic signal (by "w" I mean Omega naught):

f(t)= Cos(wt)+3sin(2wt)+5cos(6wt)

How to plot its amplitude and phase spectrum **exactly** like the format and pattern demonstrated in the attached photo? (please explain it step by step and keep it as simple as possible).[image: Amplitude and Phase of a periodic signal]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, t, w0, w, fs]
f[t_, w0_] := Cos[w0 t] + 3 Sin[2 w0 t] + 5 Cos[6 w0 t];

(*using w0=1 as example. Change as needed*)
fs = FourierTransform[f[t, 1], t, w, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]; 

mag = ComplexExpand@Abs[fs];
tab = Table[{k, mag /. w -> k}, {k, -6, 6}];
tab = tab /. DiracDelta[0] -> 1;
ListPlot[tab, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Thick, Red},     
     AxesLabel -> {"w (r/s)", "Amplitude"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
phase = ComplexExpand@Arg[fs];
tab = Table[{k, phase /. w -> k}, {k, -6, 6}];
tab = tab /. DiracDelta[0] -> 1;
ListPlot[tab, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"w (r/s)", "Phase"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

Version which uses `Pi` as units per comment below

```
ClearAll[f, t, w0, w, fs]
f[t_, w0_] := Cos[w0 t] + 3 Sin[2 w0 t] + 5 Cos[6 w0 t];

multiplier = 100; (*change as needed*)
fs = FourierTransform[f[t, multiplier*Pi], t, w, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];

mag = ComplexExpand@Abs[fs];
tab = Table[{k, mag /. w -> k}, {k, -6*multiplier Pi, 6*multiplier*Pi,
     multiplier*Pi}];
tab = tab /. DiracDelta[0] -> 1;
ListPlot[tab, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"w (r/s)", "Amplitude"},
 BaseStyle -> 10,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 Ticks -> {Range[-6*multiplier Pi, 6*multiplier*Pi, 2*multiplier*Pi], 
   Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
phase = ComplexExpand@Arg[fs];
tab = Table[{k, phase /. w -> k}, {k, -6*multiplier Pi, 
    6*multiplier*Pi, multiplier*Pi}];
tab = tab /. DiracDelta[0] -> 1;
ListPlot[tab, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"w (r/s)", "Phase"}, BaseStyle -> 10, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
 Ticks -> {Range[-6*multiplier Pi, 6*multiplier*Pi, 2*multiplier*Pi], 
   Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If w0=100 Pi, how would you modify the codes?

Comment: @Joe added version which uses `Pi`. Change as needed to fit your needs.